# Video: What are I-frames and why do they affect the size of the video?

Tags: video, keyframes

Videos usually are described by a set of parameters including: `bit rate`, `frame rate`, `width & height`.

But I came to realize that there are more parameters including `B-frames` and `I frames` (or I guess they are the KEY-FRAMES).

Now I noticed that they exist when I was working on a custom video capturing technique in which I have the ability to control how often they appear in terms of seconds, so they are either 1 sec away from each other or 2 sec away or 3.....

But some weird things happened when I tried to change the appearance of these frames.

**First case:**

When I encoded a video with (2 sec or 1 between I Frames) I got a video that doesn't seek well.

Now If I try to merge the encoded video with an equal length audio file for some reason when I seek forward or backward I see black screen before I seek to the requested frame.

**Second case:**

When I encoded a video with (0 sec between I frames) I got a video that seeks fine, but for some reason the size increased.

Now if I try to merge the encoded video with audio of equal length I get a video mixed with audio that works well and seeks well with no black screen on seeking.

**Question:**

What are I frames?

Why do they affect seek behavior?

Why do they affect the merging of video with audio?

Why do they affect the size of the video?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some research about GOPs ( Group of Pictures ) to find the definition of I frames.

This will answer the second and fourth question as well.

In generall, the more I frames a GOP has:

- the better is the seeking qualitiy. (If the seek lands to a non I frame, it takes ressources to calculate the frame. To avoid this, sometimes seeking is only possible from one I frame to another)
- the bigger is the video ( as I frames are saved as full frames )

The GOP has usually no effect on sound, but the codec does.

Comment: why is it that when I merge an audio file with a video file that was encoded with 1 sec between i -intervals I get black frames when I fast seek? But It doesn't happen when i-frames are set to 0.

Comment: If you video only contains I-frames, there's less decoding necessary and therefore frames can be shown. For non I frames the decoding is much mor time-consuming and abviously not fast enough to show the frames during seeking.

Comment: Then what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Use I frames only, or use at least only B frames in addition and no P frames, or use another codec.

Comment: Yes I am doing this but the file is getting too large? In your opinion what do you suggest( frame rate, bitrate, length, width ) should I use with a (0 sec i - interval  video) to get a video of almost length 2:00 minutes and doesn't exceed 8-7 mb?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't. You require a very small video and want it to be visible during fast seek. But the B and P frames only exist because they reduce the bitrate and therefore the filesize for the compromise that the video looses quality - not only during playback, but as well during seek. Why do you need the fast seek? Is it a workaround to find a program that doubles the speed of your audio without changing the pitch and then render the video in double speed as well?

Comment: So I can't get a 2:00 minute file to be low in size? If yes then how apps compress video before upload to server from 100mb to 20mb?

Comment: Which codec do you use and which software for the playback?

Comment: codec mp4, and playback is simply android's media controller class. Simply a controller with seekbar that allows you to seek from position to position and play button.

Comment: So it seems that the device is not fast enough to decode the video. MPEG4 is a codec that is very efficient for encoding, which means you can compress the video very high and keep a good quality, but the decoding device has to do more work to reconstruct the video. During playback this works well, the I frame has all pixels saved and the B frames afterwards save only the changes. ( Backup software supporting incremental strategies works similar. ) But if you seek the decoder has to calculate the frames faster and needs to jump between the I frames.

Comment: I appreciate all your effort I wish I can up vote but I am not allowed since I have no rep. But I just want to ask you what makes a video large in size: the dimensions, or bitrate, or frame rate or I intervals...which is the more effective?

Comment: The bitrate. Since 8 bit are 1 Byte you can calculate. Megabyte * 8 = Megabit. Megabit/s * video length = file size in Mbit / 8 = filesize in MB. If the bitrate is constant, the quality depends on the picture size (how many pixels), the framerate (how many frames, you should not change this value, snce they are normed (PAL/NTSC/...). And the I frames affect the number of pixels indirectly. To get the best possible result you should do some research on video compression.

Comment: It is usually not effective to change the picture size either. If the device on which you what the video converts the video back to the screen size (HD/SD/whatever) the effect is a quality loss which is occasionally bigger than compressing the video in it's original size.

Comment: ahh okay I understand now thanks for your help and support, you are very informative.

Comment: FYI, comments are not meant for back and forth discussion. If you need to continue the conversation, please take it to chat.

Comment: Sorry about that. We'd liked to do so, but we don't own the required Rep 20 in order to so do.